# Style not getting applied to NavigationView menu in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

Style is not being applied to the menu, not sure what is wrong here, seems ok to me. I want the drawer menu items to be bold. Am I missing something here

**activity_main.**

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/height_toolbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        style="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
        app:elevation="4dp">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    style="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
                    app:elevation="0dp"
                    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_drawer_divider"
                    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

                <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_view_footer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/bg_color"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    style="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
                    app:elevation="0dp"
                    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer_footer" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**styles.xml**

```
 <!-- navigation drawer style -->
    <style name="NavigationDrawerStyle" parent="AppTheme">

        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>
```

Also, an additional question is how can I make part of the text bold. for example, if I have menu item "Mein Garten" I want only "Mein" to be bold please check the image attached

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figured out the issue, i was applying `style` the wrong way in `NavigationView`. Here is what i changed

**before**

```
style="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
```

**after**

```
app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
```